# Must answers comply with the tags associated to the question? and other questions

Tags: discussion, tags, answers, scope

**Questions**

1. Must **answers** comply with the **tags** associated to the question?
2. What should I do if the answer is vaguely related to the question, or answers the question, but in a different context then the one described?

**Background**

I asked a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68557/6071) and I tagged it specifically `church universal`.

One answer that I received is strictly Catholic. When I underlined that I am interested in a generic principle, not a particular point of view, I was suggested to ask another question.

Now, of course, it makes no sense to ask the same question again. Even if I do, even if it is not reported as duplicated, there is the big risk that I will receive Catholic-specific answers.

Note: I do not have anything against Catholicism (or any other religion / belief). It is just the particular detail of the question and answer under discussion.

**Other questions**
3. If the Catholic points of view are favored, maybe the name of the community should be changed from "Christianity" to "Catholicism"?
4. Where can I ask a question about all-encompassing Christianity? I am not interested in general philosophy or to debate for the sake of the debate.

My question in the link remains valid, but now I do not know how to find a better answer.

Thank you all for supporting.

Comment: Answers absolutely must match the perspective asked about. The problem is your question doesn't ask about a specific perspective, letting anyone answer. There is no valid "generic principle", so you need to narrow your question.

Answer (score 6):

Tagging is to help find and sort questions - they should apply to the context of the question, questions themselves still have to have all the context in them.

So, if I tag a question [virgin-mary](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virgin-mary)  the question has to be about the Blessed Virgin Mary.  That's easy.  If I tag a question [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) the question has to be about Catholicism, not just expected to be answered by Catholics.  If I tag a question [church-universal](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-universal) the question has to be *about* the Universal Church, which is definitely defined in a way that is subjective to denominations.

If you want to ask an overview question, where the topic is Comparative Christianity, that is OK. But you must specifically ask that you want and overview and then ALL the question would be expected to cover as many denominations and sects as is appropriate to answer the question completely.  (so if someone leaves out Orthodoxy, you can't just answer with the Orthodox answer in your own answer)